# How can I use gradle submodule as a library in another modules?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, microservices

I try to write my project with four microservices, where every service need to have opportunity to call any another.

Thus I need a some client module, which will be able to call any service. And I want to use this module as a library in my services.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, You just need to create new module, then set it in settings.gradle:

```
include 'service-client'
```

And then in build.gradle of submodule where you need, add this dependency:

```
compile project(':service-client')
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using gradle 7.0 the answer from z17 needs to be amended

In the submodule it will now need to be

And then in build.gradle of submodule where you need, add this dependency:

`implementation project(':service-client')`

This is because compile has been removed from the java plugin since gradle 7.0